# Cancelling local notification on specified date

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification, uiapplication

I have problem with even inventing the posible solution for this problem.

My app needs to crate some objects of `UILocalNotification` with `interval` but if I set interval to be `NSMinuteCalendarUnit` if will bother me every minute until I cancel this notification in `UIApplication` or crash my phone with hammer...

But I'm setting in my app an end date for my project and I want those notification to work only to a specified date. Someone told me to check it when the app launches (not a problem but **what if I set this notification to be fired every minute and I won't close my app during this time?**). I need something **independent** and I want to know how to do this.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if you need to cancel the local notification in receiving one when you app is running and on the start up of you app.

When your app is running in the foreground and a local notification is fired for you app the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` is called on your App delegate.

There is not end date for local notifications thus the only way you can cancel then is from you app when it is running.

Comment: But how can I check it "when receiving notification? This solution would be fine but `UILocalNotification` is not calling any action while being fired, is it?

Comment: If you app is running then the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` on your app delegate is called.

Comment: App must be running and in foreground to receive notification. There is no end date for **recurring** notifications, but you can create notifications that fire once at a specific date and time.